# how to prevent the window from self-close when building program in sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I was learning python use sublime text2 dev.
when I code "hello world" and build it, the "cmd"window appears and disappears in a moment.
I want to make the output hold on,but I don't know how.
help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `raw_input("Press ENTER to exit")` and it will "pause" until you press a key. You should be able to add this line anywhere and as often as needed.

Comment: thanks for answer. But it doesn't work……
it says:
Press ENTER to exit
  File "D:\desktop\Sublime Text 2 Build 2220\project\hello_world.py", line 2, in <module>
    raw_input("Press ENTER to exit")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Comment: Your running it in Sublime, that's the issue. Read here as it explains how to fix this issue, http://www.bestpythonide.com/python-input-eoferror-in-sublime-text-2.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new build system. First, create a new JSON file with the following contents:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "python", "-u", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_dir"
}
```

Save it as `Packages/User/Python_cmd.sublime-build`, select `Tools -> Build System -> Python_cmd`, and build with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

`start` does what it says it does, start a new process independent of Sublime Text. `cmd` is `cmd.exe`, the Windows command-line interpreter. The `/k` flag keeps the window open (at a new command prompt) after your program has run, allowing you to examine its output, look at tracebacks, run additional commands, etc. If you don't need that functionality at some point, change it to `/c`, and the `cmd` window will close when the program is done running.

I've tested it on XP, Win7, and Win8, in both ST2 and ST3, and it works great on all of them with no changes needed.